# What is the syntax to pass Environment variables to docker image using spotify maven plugin?

Tags: maven, docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I am using the following syntax to pass enviornment variable to docker image using spotify maven plugin

> ```
> <env>
>   <Ver>3.4</Ver>
> </env>
> ```

However, the above syntax is not working.

Spotify Maven Plugin: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?